# Laravel 5.4 controller function not able to use a get request parameter from ionic 3

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, angular5

I am try to pass a from ionic application to a laravel 5.4 application, and this parameter is an array, i have been able to pass the parameter successfully but i am being able to use the parameter to select records from the database.

Here is my ionic 3 provider function:

```
 getMySmartQueues(data){
      let params = new HttpParams();
      params = params.append("sq_ids", JSON.stringify(data));

      return this.http.get(this.url + 'my/smart/queues', {params: params});
  }
```

And here is my laravel controller function:

```
public function getMySmartQueues(Request $request){

        $ids = $request['sq_ids'];

        $my_sq = SmartQueue::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

        return $my_sq;
    }
```

And here is how i subcribe to the provider function is my page:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

      this.storage.get('sq_ids').then(
          res => {
              console.log(res);
              if(res != null){
                  this.sq_ids= res;
                  console.log(this.sq_ids);

                  this.mService.getMySmartQueues(this.sq_ids).subscribe(
                      data => {
                          console.log(data);
                      }
                  );
              }
          }
      );

  }
```

But i get Server internal error. But if i have to hard code a default value for the controller function, let say like `[5,6]`, it will return the records of this `ids`, but it can not returns the records of the `ids` sent from the ionic 3 application, will be glad if any one can help me out.

Also if i change the request to a `put` request i can get the records of the `ids` sent from the ionic application. But a get request is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use controller function with `GET` you need allow  arguments in the `Route` to allow your id array.

for an example.

```
Route::get('your/url/{ids}', 'Controller@function')->name('mane_of_the_route');
```

and the controller function

```
public function getMySmartQueues(array $ids){

    $my_sq = SmartQueue::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

    return $my_sq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out, and this is what i had to do, i think it might help someone one day, i just had to `json_decode` the request like so:

```
 public function getMySmartQueues(Request $request){
        $ids = $request['sq_ids'];
        $my_sq = SmartQueue::whereIn('id', json_decode($ids))
                                ->with(
                                    'station.company'
                                )->get();
        return $my_sq;
    }
```